# Can non-recursive BGP route be used to determine next-hop for recursive BGP route?

Tags: routing, router, bgp, next-hop

In BGP recursive scenario, the recursive route is taking an unexpected next-hop. Here is the routing table:

```
S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] via 10.10.10.1, wan

B 172.16.5.0/24 [20/0] via 172.80.80.1, MPLS, 2d18h20m

B 192.168.250.0/24 [20/0] via 172.16.5.1 (recursive via 10.10.10.1), 1d1h10m
```

The next-hop of the recursive route should be the second route in the table which is another BGP route. However, it's taking the default route on top.

When adding a static route which is exactly the same as the second BGP route, next-hop is determined correctly:

```
S* 0.0.0.0/0 [10/0] via 10.10.10.1, wan

S 172.16.5.0/24 [20/0] via 172.80.80.1, MPLS

B 192.168.250.0/24 [20/0] via 172.16.5.1 (recursive via 172.80.80.1), 1d1h10m
```

Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IOS will not use another BGP route for recursive lookup for a BGP route. This is somewhat hinted at in the ["Why Routers Ignore Paths"](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13753-25.html#anc1) section of the "BGP Best Path Selection Algorithm" documentation:

> [Routers ignore] paths for which the NEXT_HOP is inaccessible.
>
> Be sure that there is an Interior Gateway Protocol (IGP) route to the NEXT_HOP that is associated with the path.

So yes, this is expected behavior on IOS. Other routing platforms may behave differently. There is also an [article](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-25771) describing further how the lookup works.

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. I wonder if this is a standard BGP behavior or vendor specific.

Comment: @onlyforthis: I suspect it's mostly standard. For example, RouterOS requires the nexthop scope [to be lower](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Route#Nexthop_lookup) than the route's own.

Comment: @onlyforthis It depends on the vendor, Juniper can use BGP routes for recursive lookup. If this answers you question please accept it as answer.